# Inserting a table into a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have done a bunch of research and tried to figure out how to do this, but everything that is suggested does not seem to work for me. I create a table using the following SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT * FROM table1_name
```

When I do this if I make changes to `table1_name` these changes are reflected in the view (as I want). However, I later create a table `table2_name` and want to add it to this view in the same way so that if I add rows to the table they will be reflected in the view. So, I use a similar piece of code, (but use insert instead)

```
INSERT INTO view_name SELECT * FROM table2_name
```

However, now when I make additions to `table2_name` these are not reflected in the view. I am extremely new to SQL (started three days ago), so any thoughts or places I should look would be extremely appreciated.

(Note: I am using SQL Server, I don't seem to think that this makes much of a difference, but in case it does)

Thanks,
SaxyTimmy

Comment: Highly recommend avoiding using SELECT *, particularly in a view. Yes it is easier to type but it can cause problems later on, especially if the schema is evolving. Using SELECT * means that you will need to refresh the view every time you change the underlying table(s). You should always explicitly specify the columns you want.

Comment: It looks like we're going to venture in the realm of metadata, can you please tag and/or specify what version of SQL Server you are using? This information is *always* useful up front.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008, sorry about that

Answer (score 6):

Maybe what you meant to do (assuming the columns are the same):

```
ALTER VIEW view_name
AS
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2_name
```

As Joe pointed out, you don't insert data into the view - it is not persisted (unless it is indexed, and in that case you don't actually insert into the view either).

If you want to update the view for new tables, you can do something like this. I'm assuming you're on SQL Server 2005 or better - if your school is teaching you SQL Server 2000, shame on them. I'm also assuming a couple of other things... your view does not contain a trailing statement terminator (about the only time I'd ever advocate leaving it out) and that you don't have all kinds of nonsense in comments before the CREATE VIEW command.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddTableToView
    @view      SYSNAME,
    @new_table SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @sql = [definition] FROM sys.sql_modules
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@view);

    SELECT @sql = STUFF(@sql, CHARINDEX('CREATE VIEW', @sql), 6, 'ALTER')
        + 'UNION ALL
           SELECT col1, col2 FROM ' + @new_table;

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
END
GO
```

But as I suggested in the comments, this really isn't the way you wanted to go, and I suspect your professor will feel the same way.

Comment: This looks quite promising. However, what if there is a large amount of tables in the view? Is there any way to use what the current view has and add onto it?

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding the concept of a view. There is no data *IN* the view... it is not a copy of the table, it is just a pointer to the table. Or do you mean that you don't want to have to re-create the view definition every time? I have a hard time following when you say "tables in the view" whether you mean actual data or references to the tables.

Comment: If you're adding a large number of identical tables to a view, it could be a sign that there's a problem with your database design.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. 

What you have is what I want to do, I just don't want to have to know which tables are currently referenced by the view prior to doing the update.

Comment: Well you can look up the existing definition in sys.sql_modules and just append to it. But how are you going to prevent adding the same view multiple times? And do you really have this many tables *with identical columns* that this is something you need to automate? Are you trying to automate some kind of partitioning scheme without actually using partitioning?

Comment: What I am trying to do makes no sense now that I understand databases a bit better. However, this is for my fourth year design project in Computer Engineering (and I have never used a database before this, I normally do Operating System programming).

I thought it would be faster have one table per user as I rarely have to deal with the data agregated together. Single users would be updated and have stats run on them daily, but I would need to do comparisons of these users based on a hierarchical structure (where they live) on a monthly basis (the time this takes to run doesn't matter).

Comment: Unfortunately my project is due too soon and I don't have the time to change the database structure now. I had originally thought views would work to provide me with an easy way of accessing these multiple tables. I just need to be able to justify that this pattern works and if your view updating strategy ends up working I will be OK (even if its not optimal), and I will describe what I woudl have done instead. Thanks :)

Comment: No, a table per user is definitely NOT the way you should have gone. Maybe you should have asked your question before your project was due. :-\

Comment: Yes, I know and I agree now. This project is extremely large with a number of complex components (it should allow for a startup company to be spawned upon completion (in 4 months)). The previous portions just took a long time and from our research we thought we understood databases, when we started implementing them, we found out we did not.

Comment: I've added a sample that shows how to build the ALTER VIEW command dynamically.

Comment: Thank you very much. Our school doesn't teach us databases until next term. Our Professor will therefore likely not be able to penalize us based on this. I appreciate your help so much :)

Comment: Eh... I hate doing things in such a hackish way, I think I am going to end up pulling an allnighter to fix my design to be correct. Thank you so much for your help, and seeing how I would go about doing this sort of thing was really helpful. You have taught me so much :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert data into a view in the way you think you can. When you run your insert statement, you are actually inserting the data into the base table (`table1_name`) that the view references. You are not creating some kind of link between the view and the rows of `table2_name`.

Comment: The base table that the view references? Would this be table1_name in my example? I look at this and no new data has been added here.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are misunderstanding what exactly a view is. A view is basically just a stored query. You don't actually insert rows into a view. Although you can have an updateable view, it is inserting rows into the underlying table.

If you want to add `table2_name` to the view then you need to change that view definition. If the columns exactly match `table1_name` then you can do something like:

```
ALTER VIEW view_name
AS
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table1_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table2_name
```

Alternatively, you can `DROP` and `CREATE` the view with the new definition instead of using the `ALTER` syntax.

Also, when you say, "if I make changes to table1_name" do you mean inserting rows or adding columns?

Comment: I mean inserting rows. I tried doing

ALTER VIEW view_name
AS
SELECT * FROM table1_name
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM view_name

does this make sense? I want to keep the old view, and add this new table to it?

Thanks!

Comment: I can answer that myself actually. No that doesn't make sense you cannot self-reference a view. Any idea of how I could do something similar to that?

Comment: Again, you're looking at views the wrong way. They are not a persisted table/object. They are simply a query definition. Imagine that I'm making a home video of my daughters, but only one is in the frame. I don't draw the other daughter onto the camera lens, I change the view of the camera to fit them both into the picture.

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to update the view by "zooming out" where I take whats in the view and just add some more stuff to it (whats on the border of the lens).

Comment: Then you need to change the view definition to add those additional tables as I've done. It looks like the comments in Aaron's answer are moving in the right direction, so I'd stick with that instead of maintaining both conversations.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert data into a view. Your insert inserts data into the `table1_name` table. (See [Updatable and Insertable Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html))

If you want data from both `table1_name` and `table2_name` then you have to have both `table1_name` and `table2_name` in the `select` based on which the view is created.

You can use **either** [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)* for that (if both the tables you query from have the same no/type/set of columns):

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT * FROM table1_name
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2_name
```

This requires that `table1_name` and `table2_name` have the same number and types of columns in the same order

**Or** you can join with the other table and get all the columns (or a subset of them):

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT * 
FROM table1_name join table2_name on some_column
```

*`UNION` removes the duplicates between the two select queries. `UNION ALL` is a better option if you are sure that the data from both tables are mutually exclusive, or if you are ok with the duplicate rows. `UNION ALL` performs better.